# Block certain IP from accesing you AWS EC

Tags: php, security, amazon-web-services

my question is regarding Amazon web services.

The problem:
I want to be able to block only certain IP's from accessing an instance of mine. I read about the topic and first i thought that security groups would do the trick, but ... the rules in them are only permissive(net restrictive).

My question is - is there a way to dynamicly "ban certain IP's"  from accessing my webpage(some server instance) through my websites administration(i would like to do this dinamicly using the AWS SDK(php)).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution to this is going to end up being to employ a second level firewall, installed directly on the ec2 instance to further filter traffic that the security groups let in.

In addition, you can use Elastic Load Balancer to offload *some* DDos protection (if that is the problem) for your site if you make sure your ec2 instance only accepts traffic from the ELB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i`ll see to try this solution. I explored a simular solution with IPtables, but the problem is that they are instance specific and i`ll have to maintain iptables for every instance i have. 

A solution is to use ACL`s but they are useable only with VPC, which i don`t have.
Thanks again, i`ll try read about the possibility to offload traffic via the ELB,